# No flutter, existe alguma diferença entre usar as dependencies?

Tags: flutter, semântica

Olá, no `pubspec.yaml`, existe alguma diferença entre usar as dependencias `depedencies` e `dev-dependencies`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da [documentação](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies) da linguagem podemos ver que:

> Dev dependencies differ from regular dependencies in that dev dependencies of packages you depend on are ignored.

Isto é, traduzindo, a diferença é que você não obtém as `dev_dependencies` de pacotes que você importa. Ou seja, o intuito das `dev_dependencies` é ser usado para colocar as dependências que você usa para desenvolver (eg. testes unitários, testes de performance), mas que não são necessárias para o uso de sua biblioteca.

De maneira geral, se você vai importar um pacote dentro de sua pasta `lib`, então ele é uma `dependency`. Alternativamente, se você importa ele de dentro de outras pastas `test`, `example` etc, então ele deve ser uma `dev-dependency`.

Comment: Eu estava colocando no dev_dependencies, mas não importa onde eu coloque meu app funciona de boas. Exemplos das que uso:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  flutter_svg: 0.17.3+1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5